# R - Collapse By Row

Tags: r, paste

I need to collapse my data **by row**.

```
seq = structure(c("h", "d", "s", "s", "f", "k", "s", "s", "f", "d", 
"d", "d", "l", "l", "d", "d"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("act1.055", "act1.056", "act1.057", "act1.058")))
```

My data look like this :

```
     act1.055 act1.056 act1.057 act1.058
[1,] "h"      "f"      "f"      "l"     
[2,] "d"      "k"      "d"      "l"     
[3,] "s"      "s"      "d"      "d"     
[4,] "s"      "s"      "d"      "d"
```

If I do

```
paste(seq, collapse = "")
[1] "hdssfkssfdddlldd"
```

which is not what I want.

What I need is

```
hffl
dkdl 
ssdd 
ssdd
```

In a matrix if possible.

Comment: Maybe we need a `rowPaste` function?

Comment: @BondedDust - Definitely !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
matrix(apply(seq, 1, paste, collapse=''), ncol=1)
#     [,1]  
#[1,] "hffl"
#[2,] "dkdl"
#[3,] "ssdd"
#[4,] "ssdd"
```

Comment: Happy to help! Quicknote: avoid naming variables after functions. Confusion may ensue.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
matrix(do.call(paste0, data.frame(seq)))
```

Output:

```
     [,1]  
[1,] "hffl"
[2,] "dkdl"
[3,] "ssdd"
[4,] "ssdd"
```